# How does C# handle threads switching?

Tags: c#, winforms, multithreading, label

I am working on an application where two threads execute a method from a class simultaneously. This method performs some complex calculations and the result is displayed in a WinForm.

So my class looks like:

```
class Comp_func
{
    /* Constructor */
    public Comp_func()
    {
    }

    public void THE_Complex_func(string One, Int16 Two, Int32 Three)
    {
        Calculate_this(One);
        Thread.Sleep(10);
        Calculate_that(Two);
        Thread.Sleep(10);
        Calculate_thatThat(Three);
        Thread.Sleep(10);
        Update_lable_in_form(value);
        Thread.Sleep(10);
    }
}
```

Each thread updates different `Label` in the WinForm so, I expect no issues about thread synchronization (as I have used Thread Safe Methods).

My need is those updates should occur simultaneously (at least seem to occur simultaneously).

When the user clicks on a "Calculate" button in my form, I do:

```
Comp_func Func1_class = new Comp_func();
Comp_func Func2_class = new Comp_func();

Thread Func1_Thread = new Thread(() => Func1_class.Start_Test("Blah", 2,3));
Thread Func2_Thread = new Thread(() => Func2_class.Start_Test("BlahBlah", 4,5));

//Func1_Thread.Priority = ThreadPriority.Highest;  /* Deleted after Comments */
   // Func2_Thread.Priority = ThreadPriority.Highest;  /* Deleted after Comments */


Func1_Thread.Start();
Func2_Thread.Start();

/*
  //  Removed after Comments 

// Let only Threads Run
 while(true)
{
    Application.DoEvent();
    Update();
}

for(count = 0; count < 100; count++)
 {  
    console.WriteLine("I WON'T USE WHILE(1) loops with DOEVENTS");
 }

*/
```

My problem is that when execution of Thread 1 completes, it updates the `Label`, and then Thread 2 starts and executes.

In order to avoid this behavior, I wrote `Thread.Sleep();` after almost each line. It still behaves as if windows did not take care of switching!

Any idea why this is happening?

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: What is it that you are expecting to happen?  Side note on several things that are usually considered bad practice; explicitly stating thread priority, infinite loop. Why do you need the Thread.Sleep lines?

Comment: My Problem is thread is not switching properly. Execution is like, Thread 1 completes and then Thread 2. So I thought Thread.Sleep will force the Threads to Switch.

Comment: How do you know that the threads are not switching? going by your function calls you only update the UI once in each thread - when each one has completed its work.  with the code you have thread 1 will always complete before thread 2.

Comment: If you have taken on board everything that dice and Martin James have said your program should do what you want. As a guideline for simple multithreading (if that's not a contradiction in itself) is to avoid explicitly defining the behaviour. The people who wrote the threading classes know far more about it than the majority of developers. So don't change priorities and don't force Sleep unless you really know why they're required

Comment: @dice I want that Two Lables in UI should update simultainously... Means they should look updating almost at the same time but it's like Lable I updates and then after say 1 sec, Lable II updates! How to do that? And I put some "OutputDebugStrings" there also shows Thread 1 debug strings and then Thread 2 debug strings.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code example is quite incomplete - so it is difficult to see what is going on.

the first comment I would have is that you should not have an infinite loop in your click handler - in fact you shouldn't need the `while(true)..DoEvent()` code at all

In response to your requirement that the two labels update simultaneously the best thing to do is have the threads join before updating the UI - one method to do this would be to create a BackgroundWorker that kicks off the other two threads, Join()s them, then updates the UI with the two results - depending on the version of .net you are running you may be able to use the Tasks library to do it with less code.

here is a rather crude implementation (if you don't have the Tasks library available):

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        BackgroundWorker master= new BackgroundWorker();
        master.DoWork += (sender1, e1) =>
                              {
                                  Thread t1 = new Thread(Func1_class.Start_Test);
                                  Thread t2 = new Thread(Func1_class.Start_Test);
                                  t1.Start();
                                  t2.Start();
                                  t1.Join();
                                  t2.Join();
                              };
        master.RunWorkerCompleted += (sender2, e2) =>
                                          {
                                              label1.Text = "text";
                                              label2.Text = "text";
                                          };
        master.RunWorkerAsync();
    }
```

Comment: This is sort of Test code I wrote to explain condtion to you guys. And I want to process Some timer functions and Update form through thread so I wrote that DoEvent() and Update()   :(

Comment: 'process Some timer functions' - Windows.Forms.Timers will work just fine if you just exit the OnClick handler. 'Update form through thread', (using Invoke/BeginInvoke), will work just fine if you just exit the OnClick handler.

Answer (score 2):

Get rid of the sleep() calls and the DoEvents() loop, as suggested by @dice - they are not helping, no matter how much you think they are.  If you are correctly Invoke/BeginInvoke-ing the label changes, you should be fine - just exit the OnClick event-handler.  You should not wait in GUI event handlers.

Repeat - don't try to wait in a GUI event handler.

How many processor cores do you have, and why have you raised the priority of the work threads?  If you only have one CPU and you start a CPU-intensive task on Func1_Thread, it will run on, using 100% CPU, until it stops itself or the Windows anti-starvation algorithm gives the other threads a few cycles after 30 seconds.  This will give the impression of serialization.

Raising threads to a high priority and then inserting sleep() calls is just... well, just don't do it!

Comment: Thanks for Suggestions.... Will remember this! But I inserted Thread.Sleep for switching... I thought Sleeping one thread will wake up another.... Priority was a trial.... And I run on a Dual core 3GHz Machine!

Answer (score 1):

There's something you really don't understand about threads.

You have no way to know for sure how the OS will handle the execution of the threads.
If you want to change the labels simultaneously you'll have to do it yourself.

For exemple at the end of your super function raise an event, for exemple let's call it SuperCalcDone.
On your SuperCalcDone handler just check if all your calculations are done and then update the labels.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but I want that It should go on updating... And Also this was example, In real code, I need to update lables almost after each function. Also there are 14 such functions. :( And Two threads are processing independant data!